# Add base64 encoded image as attachment with MailCore2

Tags: objective-c, image, smtp, base64, mailcore2

In my application I have an image which is already encoded as base64

data:image/jpeg;base64,...

Now I want to attach this image to a email which is build and can be send with MailCore2.

The code I have so far is:

```
MCOMessageBuilder * builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];

...

MCOAttachment *attachment = [MCOAttachment attachmentWithText:textAttachment];
[builder addAttachment:attachment];

NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];
MCOSMTPSendOperation *sendOperation = [smtpSession sendOperationWithData:rfc822Data];
[sendOperation start:^(NSError *error) {
    ...
}
```

This already sends out the mail correctly except for the fact that the image is not attached as image, but as text (because I attached it as such with attachmentWithText).

So far I have already tried replacing this with attachmentWithHTMLString but the result is similar (except for the fact that it is now more separated from the text body).

I guess it could work if I surround the data with the proper html image syntax like this:

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,...' />
```

but maybe not. Or do I even have to build a whole small html page for it?

Unfortunately the MailCore2 documentation is not very verbose with information about how to send email attachments.

So if anyone has experience with MailCore2, please tell me the most efficient way to attach an image to an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my guess to surround the data with a proper HTML tag already did the trick sufficiently:

I immediately got the desired result when I sent

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,...' />
```

instead of just the data in combination with attachmentWithHTMLString like this

```
MCOAttachment *attachment = [MCOAttachment attachmentWithHTMLString:textAttachment];
```

where textAttachment contains "".

I guess this is already the most efficient way, but I leave the answer open just in case anyone has an even better solution.

Comment: I added some information to the original wiki: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/wiki/SMTP-Examples and mark this as accepted answer.